# Formal solution of the Langevin equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, differential-equations, stochastic-processes

The 1-Dimensional Langevin equation is given by
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} x = - \gamma x + \sqrt{\gamma} \xi (t)
$$
How can I solve this equation for the $x(t)$ with initial conditions $x(0)$? Is the solution for the position is same as for the velocity $v(t)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a first order linear ordinary differential equation so it can always be solved using an integrating factor. In particular, we want to multiply the whole equation by a function I such that
$$\frac{d}{dt}(Ix)=I\left(\frac{dx}{dt}+\gamma x\right).$$
This equation can be reduced to
$$\frac{dI}{dt}=I\gamma .$$
In particular, we can choose $I(t)=e^{\gamma t}$. With this factor, the differential equation becomes
$$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{\gamma t}x)=\frac{d}{dt}(Ix)=I\sqrt{\gamma}\xi(t)=\sqrt{\gamma}e^{\gamma t}\xi(t).$$
Integrating this from $0$ to $t$ you obtain
$$e^{t\gamma}x(t)-x(0)=\int_0^tdt\frac{d}{dt}(e^{\gamma t}x)=\sqrt{\gamma}\int_0^tdt e^{\gamma t}\xi(t).$$
Thus, the final solution is
$$x(t)=e^{-t\gamma}\left(x(0)+\sqrt{\gamma}\int_0^tdt e^{\gamma t}\xi(t)\right).$$
Differentiating with respect to time we obtain
$$v(t)=-\gamma e^{-t\gamma}\left(x(0)+\sqrt{\gamma}\int_0^tdt e^{\gamma t}\xi(t)\right)+\sqrt{\gamma}\xi(t),$$
which is not the same as $x(t)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But in the first expression  $$ \frac{d}{dt}(Ix)=I\left(\frac{dx}{dt}+\gamma x\right).$$, how you get this form of the Langevin equation?

Comment: This is the standard method of solving first order linear ODEs with an integrating factor. It has nothing to do with the Langevin equation. In general, if you have an equation of the form $y'+A(x)y=B(x)$, the solution can be found by multiplying the whole equation by a function $I(x)$ which makes the left hand side a total derivative. So, what we want is to find a function $I(x)$ such that $I(x)(y'+A(x)y)=(I(x)y)'$. If one succeeds in finding such an $I(x)$, the resulting equation is $(I(x) y)' =I(x)B(x)$. This equation is trivial to solve since it is separable, i.e. solvable by integrating.

Comment: Moreover, finding $I(x)$ is always possible since the equation $(I(x)y)'=I(x)(y' +A(x)y)$ reduces to $I'(x)=I(x)A(x)$. In other words, $\log(I(x))'=A(x)$. Thus, integrating we can find the logarithm of $I$ and then exponentiating we can find $I$. In the Langevin equation this is easy since $A$ is a constant.